# Selenium IDE fails to find components

Tags: javascript, selenium, xpath, selenium-ide, oracle-adf

I'm testing an ADF application with Selenium IDE. At one point, the automated test case has to click on a button, which has a `partialTrigger` attribute pointing to a table on the page and after the button executes some background logic, the table is populated with rows, but the **page is not fully refreshed**.

The problem I'm facing is that the Selenium IDE can't find the table rows after the button click. Possibly, Selenium is not aware of the page's DOM update, but I'm not sure about that.

What I have tried so far is this:

1. I stored the expected full xpath for a cell in the first row of the table.
2. Created a self-executing JavaScript function that is used for clicking on the given path.
3. I have tested the following commands on a simple HTML page and they work fine.

Selenium commands:

```
<tr>
    <td>store</td>
    <td>//html[1]/body[1]/div[1]/table[1]/tbody[1]/tr[1]/td[1]</td>
    <td>myTableRowPath</td> <!-- store the xpath with name 'myTableRowPath' -->
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>storeEval</td>
    <td>(function(path) { 
         var result = selenium.browserbot.getUserWindow()
                     .document.evaluate(path,
                                        selenium.browserbot.getUserWindow().document,
                                        null, 
                                        8, 
                                        null).singleNodeValue; result.click(); 
                     return null;
        })
        (${myTableRowPath})
   </td>
    <td>elementToBeClicked</td>
</tr>
```

How can I make Selenium IDE aware of any (AJAX) DOM updates on the page ?

Comment: @kocko: Why change the tag to Java? Just because the server side is on JavaEE doesn't affect this question. It could just as well be serving purely static HTML, which is fetched by AJAX on the page. Question is about how to adapt to changes on the page with Selenium IDE, not how to do some server side tricks. Furthermore, Selenium IDE can be scripted with JavaScript, which is what the OP tried, thus editing the tag from JavaScript to Java seems all kinds of wrong.

Comment: Fair enough, I removed it.

Answer (score 2):

Generally when dealing with AJAX on Selenium IDE, you'll want to use a `waitForElementPresent` type of action.

For instance if your table changes from

```
<table id="myTable">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>foo</td>
      <td>bar</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

to

```
<table id="myTable">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>foo</td>
      <td>bar</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>something</td>
      <td>else</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

You can use:

```
<tr>
    <td>click</td>
    <td>//input[@id='myButton']</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>waitForElementPresent</td>
    <td>//table[@id='myTable']/tbody/tr[2]</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>assertText</td>
    <td>//table[@id='myTable']/tbody/tr[2]/td</td>
    <td>something</td>
</tr>
```

[Here's](http://jsfiddle.net/j5c52/1/) a JSFiddle I tested it against (no AJAX, but simulating that with a slow JS function).

Comment: This is the trivial solution, but for some reason it's not working when applied to ADF.

Comment: I don't suppose you'd have an example of an ADF page, where this doesn't work or more information how it differs from your run-of-the-mill web page?

Answer (score 2):

ADF manipulate the generated HTML in a way that it'll be very hard to maintain an XPath. The easiest way to target specific elements in ADF is giving this element a styleClass and access it using the class attribute.

Comment: Well that's an answer that makes more sense. I will definetely try it out ! Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

1. ADF loads the table UI (whose ID selenium is looking for) before it loads the contents of the table. It is possible your webdriver is looking for the content before it is loaded, so you could explicitly wait for a short period of time before clicking on the row.
2. Your table might be using lazy load which only loads the contents of the table when you scroll it into view. If your window only shows 5 rows and there are 10 rows in your table, your browser will only load 5 rows. If you ask selenium to look for row 8, it will throw an exception. I solved this by clicking on the first row and driver.switchTo().activeElement().sendKeys(Keys.DOWN); for the number of times the number of the row I am searching for. So I am "scrolling" to the row before accessing it